# Rails: Using custom column to look up for has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

I have 3 models: User, List, Following

I'm trying to implement a system, where

- A user can create many lists (list contains photos, but it's not relevant in this question)
- A user can follow lists created by other users

Here's how I'm trying to build this system:

First we have a database table of lists:

`lists: id, user_id`

And specifying the models like the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
end
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

We can do `User.first.lists` without problem.

Now my challenge comes when trying to create the followership. I'd like a user to be able to find

1. All the lists he's following
2. All the lists being followed that are created by him
3. All the users following his lists (or, equivalently, all "followers")

Here's the database table I'm trying to use to fulfill the above function:

`followings: user_id, list_id, list_user_id`

In this table definition, `user_id` specifies who's following the list, `list_id` specifies the list being followed, and `list_user_id` specifies the owner of the list being followed. `list_user_id` is used here to speed up the database lookups, so that we don't have to join `lists` table with `users` table.

And now I'm stuck. I tried to change the user model to the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
  has_many :followings

  # Works
  has_many :following_lists, :through => :followings, :class_name => "List", :source => :list

  # Doesn't work
  has_many :followed_lists, :through => :followings, :class_name => "List", :source => :list, :conditions => {:list_user_id => self.id}

  # Doesn't work
  has_many :followers, :through => :followings, :class_name => "User", :source => :user
end
```

The first goal, "Find all the lists he's following", is done, through `has_many :following_lists`, without problem. However, it seems it's difficult to get "all lists being followed" and "all followers" of a user.

The problem is that there seems to be no way to specify the key to use for lookup in the `followings` table. For example, when looking for user A's followers, I'll need to find all rows in `followings` table where the `list_user_id` equals `A.id`, but `has_many` method doesn't provide an option to do this, nor does the condition `:conditions => {:list_user_id => self.id}` work (it'll complain `undefined method 'id'`).

So..how would you deal with this situation? Is there a better way to design the tables, or can we actually work out something based on the current table definitions?

Btw, here's how `Following` model is defined:

```
class Following < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :list_id, :list_user_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :list_user, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get these 2 things:

1.) All the lists being followed that are created by him

2.) All the users following his lists (or, equivalently, all "followers")

Both of these are filtering on top of lists owned by the user. Therefore the associations with :through => followings are incorrect. Since that scopes the lists to ones you follow, not ones you own.

One way to do want you want would be like this:

```
def followed_lists
  # This essentially limits your owned lists to ones with an entry in the followings table
  lists.join(:followings).all
end

def users_following_owned_lists
  lists.followers.all
end
```

You will need to add the followers association to the List AR.

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followings

  has_many :followers, :through => :followings, :class_name => "User", :source => :user
end
```

Note also that list_user_id on followings table is not really needed.

Comment: Thanks Cal! The first one - `followed_lists` - works as expected, returning all followed lists. But trying second one, `lists.followers.all`, it complains `NoMethodError: undefined method 'followers' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fa041c068e8>`. I did put `has_many :followers, ...` line into `List` model, and I can indeed do `list.followers` without problem. Is it possibly because when using the plural form, `lists`, rails can't associate the SQL like in singular form?